# Mapbox GL JS Unable to read local GeoJSON file

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm trying to add my GeoJSON file so that I can display the locations (as circles for now), and I have validated this file on geojson.io as well as geojsonlint.com. Here's the current code:

```
map.on("load", function () {
          map.addSource("my-data", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: "../carparks.geojson",
          });

          map.addLayer({
            id: "my-layer",
            type: "circle",
            source: "my-data",
            paint: {
              "circle-radius": 6,
              "circle-color": "#ffffff", 
              "circle-stroke-color": "green", 
              "circle-stroke-width": 2, 
            },
          });
```

I have also checked that carparks.geojson is in the parent directory of the current directory. However, it doesn't work and the circles do not show on my map.

The code only works (i.e. the circles will display) if I host the exact same data on a web server (I host it on my own GitHub using GitHub Pages), i.e.

```
map.on("load", function () {
          map.addSource("my-data", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: "https://github.com/my-github-username/repo-name/carparks.geojson",
          });
```

However, I'm sure there's a way to use a local GeoJSON file instead of having to host it online.

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to tell from your code what is the issue. Most probably mapbox can't load the file. See the browser console for errors loading `carparks.geojson`. You most probably have to adjust the url.

If it doesn't work, then try loading it first and only then adding layer with `data` set to the contents of GeoJSON itself (example here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/).

You can as well create the source first and use `setData`, like so:

```
map.getSource('my-data').setData(yourData)
```